# Drawing a gameboard

Tags: tikz-pgf

I desperately need help drawing a board for a board game  which looks like the one in the picture or an even better one. The corners could be made to look more appealing visually. 
[image: boards game background]

Comment: What are your efforts so far? If you have never used TikZ before, a good starting point is the [PGF manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). It also helps when you post a full, compilable TeX document showing where your problem is, so that people can help you more easily.

Answer (score 5):

You can start with some thing like this:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[b/.style={draw,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=3.5cm,rounded corners}]
\path node(n)[b]at (0,0){} node[b,scale=.75]{};
\path[draw] (n.north east) edge [shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt](n.south west) (n.north west)edge [shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt](n.south east) (n.north)--(n.south) (n.east)--(n.west) node at(0,0)[b,scale=.5,fill=white]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```